# Adding to a legend after each iteration

Tags: matlab, legend

I run

```
loglog(x,y);
legend('First script');
```

from the first script.
Then, `hold on;`.
I run a similar second script.
I see two graphs correctly, but only the initial legend.
I want to increment the legend from different scripts.

**How can you add to the legend from a single script?**

Comment: Appending entries to a legend is not possible, so you have to construct a new legend using data from the current legend. A possible solution is given here: http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-181SJ/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Another possible way to do this and it is called 'DisplayName':

```
hold all
for ind=1:3
x=[0:0.1:10];
plot(x, sin(x)+ind, 'DisplayName',['sin + ' num2str(ind)]);
end
legend(gca,'show')
```

Just use this property when plotting from wherever to whatever axes :)

There are even more things possible, like dynamic legend!

For more information see this: [dynamic legend from undocumented matlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/legend-semi-documented-feature/)

**EDIT**

you have to update the legend after every run of a script. you can do this with the dynamic legend or by just legend('off'); legend('show')

Comment: This is a neat feature, but you don't get the legend until you have already plotted everything.  `-dynamicLegend` on the other hand is a great solution, at least in principle.  Hopefully MathWorks can work out the bugs in this latter feature (zoom throws errors).

Comment: @chappjc well, about the error when zooming in, i recommend reading the article on undocumented matlab. Yair Altman explains how to get rid of this :) About the legend showing up: I dont get what you mean by "dont get the legend until you have plotted everything". Perhaps you mean, that it doesnt update automatically. if one needs that, just turn the legend off and on again...

Comment: That's exactly right, and turning off and on is a solution I give in my answer. The OP wants to run code, generating the plot and legend, look at it, run a second arbitrary script, look at it with updated legend,... (right?) you don't get that if `legend` is only called after the loop. `DisplayName` is nice, but it is not what gets you a dynamic legend like the OP wants -- inside the loop you need `legend('off');legend('show');` right after plot. It's a fairly trivial change as we know, but that is a solution. Anyway, it would be nice if MATLAB just offered an `'auto'` option for legend. :)

Comment: @chappjc I see! didnt understand the question like that... Just thought the OP was asking about how to put information to the legend. And well DisplayName and cell-array of strings are useful for that. for updating the legend using legend(off/on) and dynamiclegend are both possible.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to deal with this is to save the handle to the legend when you create it, then whey you are ready to update the plot with a new legend with another series included, delete the legend and make a new one:

```
legendStrings = {'First script'};
h_legend = legend(legendStrings{:});
% ... computations, hold on and additional plot on axis
delete(h_legend);
legendStrings{end+1} = 'Second script';
h_legend = legend(legendStrings{:});
% rinse and repeat...
```

Usually with graphics objects, such as a textbox, I would say just reuse the object via the handle (don't `delete`).  However, if you *update* the legend instead of *replacing* it, you have to worry about more than just the strings.  The [MathWorks solution referenced by zroth](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-181SJ/) actually seems to address this approach!

As an alternatively to `delete` and create new, you can also toggle the legend on and off with `legend('off'); legend('show');` as the answer in Eugenio's comment suggests.

Comment: Simple answer, not possible, only work around available. So much easier to just write the legends again lastly.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is:

```
hold all;
p1=plot(1:10,1:10);  
legend(p1,'1');  % in this way plot(x,y) is saved as variable p1 with name '1'   
p2=plot(1:10,11:20); % different data set

legend(p2,'2');  
legend(gca,'off');    
legend('show');
```

This is connection of few methods, it's very simple and it could be use everywhere.

Comment: awesome, +1. What does legend(gca,'off') do?

Comment: @user3804598 In case you were still wondering, legend(gca, 'off') is paired with the line directly below it. Essentially it turns the legend off (the line below turns it back on), which forces Matlab to refresh and display new legend changes.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue: I plotted three sets of experimental data first, then got into my parameter estimation to simulate the function and wanted to plot the model data every time, holding on to the experimental data but deleting the model data from the previous run. And I wanted the legend to show that. I was able to do it with a combination of solutions from different questions.

**Initial commands (top of my main)**

`close all` will ensure your plot starts anew every time

**First plot (in my main)**

```
plot(points,expdata1,'ro','DisplayName','Experimental, L= 0.1 m'); hold on
plot(points,expdata2,'bo','DisplayName','Experimental, L= 0.2 m'); 
plot(points,expdata3,'go','DisplayName','Experimental, L= 0.3 m');   
legend('-DynamicLegend','Location','Best')
drawnow
h_old=plot(0,250);
```

`drawnow` forces the plot to be drawn right away, and `h_old` is just a "placeholder" that I make use of later on. I chose 0,250 because it's in the range of the data (otherwise it messes up the axis)

**Second Plot (in the called function)**

```
h(1)=plot(points,modeldata1,'r-','DisplayName','Model Data, L= 0.1 m');
h(2)=plot(points,modeldata2,'b-','DisplayName','Model Data, L= 0.2 m'); 
h(3)=plot(points,modeldata3,'g-','DisplayName','Model Data, L= 0.3 m');
delete(h_old);
h_old = h;
drawnow
```

I delete `h_old` and overwrite it with the new plots I created. That way, at the second iteration the plot from the 2nd iteration will be plotted, the plot from the 1st will be deleted and after these operations I get it to display the plot (again `drawnow`).

Answer (score 0):

```
plot(x,y);
legend('y');

hold on;
plot(x,z);
hold off;

% Now add a new item to the legend

h = legend();
newleg = h.String;
newleg{end+1} = 'z';
legend(newleg);
```

Comment: While this may be the answer the OP is looking for, you should provide an explanation with your code. simply pasting code isn't really helping the OP understand their errors or mistakes and does little to better the knowledge of future viewers of this question.