# Dynamic Legend (Updates in every recursion)

Tags: matlab, legend, matlab-figure, figure

I got a  `for i=1:15`. Inside I generate a variable `d=1:0.01:10`, which is the x'x axis and based on this, I create a continuous function F(d) which has 2 unique variables pitch and yaw. I then plot this using different colors in every recursion using `cmap = hsv(15);`. So then it is:

```
d=1:0.01:10;
cmap = hsv(15);

for i=1:15
    pitch = unidrnd(10);
    yaw   = unidrnd(10);

    for j=1:length(d)
        F(j) = d(j)*3*pitch*yaw; %// some long calculation here
    end

    p1 = plot(d,F,'Linewidth', 1.0);
    title ('blah blah')
    set(p1, 'Color', cmap(i,:));
    hold on;
    legend (['pitch,yaw:', num2str(pitch) num2str(yaw)]) 
end 
hold off;
```

This code updates the unique pitch, yaw values in every recursion (without space between them so it is kind irritating) but fails to:

> 1. Apply the proper color, visible in the figure.
> 2. Hold the color from the previous iteration and the values of `pitch,yaw`.

Comment: Not sure what you want to do, but [`drawnow`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/drawnow.html) at the end of each iteration may be useful

Comment: Unfortunately, `drawnow` changes nothing.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

### Semidocumented Solution

Adding lines to a legend in a loop can be accomplished with "dynamic legends", [as described on undocumentedmatlab.com](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/legend-semi-documented-feature/).

The idea is to replace the `legend` command with:

```
legend('-DynamicLegend');
```

Then update the `plot` command with a `DisplayName` parameter:

`plot(d,F,'Linewidth',1.0,'DisplayName',sprintf('pitch,yaw: %d,%d',pitch,yaw));`

Then plots that are added to the axes get added to the legend:

[image]

If semi-documented features are not your cup of tea, use the `DisplayName` trick and simply toggle the `legend` off/on. That is, instead of `-DynamicLegend`:

```
legend('off'); legend('show');
```

A [different variation that does not use either `DisplayName` or `-DynamicLegend`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19418735/2778484) is to delete and recreate the legend with an array of stored strings.

### Official Solution

The [official solution recommended by MathWorks](https://web.archive.org/web/20130627193301/http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-181SJ/?) it so grab the existing legends` line handles and manually update the legend with those handles.  This is pretty painful by comparison to the dynamic legend solution above:

```
% Get object handles
[LEGH,OBJH,OUTH,OUTM] = legend;

% Add object with new handle and new legend string to legend
legend([OUTH;p1],OUTM{:},sprintf('pitch,yaw: %d,%d',pitch,yaw))
```

Comment: Awesome use of the .gif!

Comment: This does the trick with the colors but I cannot add the values needed instead of the word data%d. +1 for the .gif though!

Comment: There's a method for that (`'DisplayName`), updated.

Comment: Great.  Also note that you can specify color in the `plot` command: `p1=plot(d,F,'Linewidth', 1.0,'DisplayName', sprintf('pitch,yaw: %d,%d',pitch,yaw), 'Color', cmap(i,:));`

Comment: Holy $*!(#*!.  I didn't know MATLAB had dynamic legends.  Also +1 for the `.gif` use.

Comment: The above link http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-181SJ/ doesn't work. :-(

Comment: I expanded the case about the dynamic legend of one graph here http://stackoverflow.com/q/39807194/54964

Answer (score 1):

As an HG2 (default in R2014+) alternative to @chappjc's official MW solution, one can take advantage of legend being re-implemented as its own class rather than a kludge of other graphics objects. This has cleaned up things a bit so they are simpler to interact with.

Though these new `legend` objects do not have an [exposed property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend-properties.html) linking legend items to plotted objects, they do have such a property, `'PlotChildren'`, which is an array of object handles.

For example:

```
x = 1:10;
y1 = x;
y2 = x + 1;

figure
plot(x, y1, 'ro', x, y2, 'bs');
lh = legend({'Circle', 'Square'}, 'Location', 'NorthWest');

pc = lh.PlotChildren
```

Returns:

```
pc = 

  2x1 Line array:

  Line    (Circle)
  Line    (Square)
```

[image: step1]

To update our `legend` object without calling `legend` again, we can modify the `'PlotChildren'` and `'String'` properties of our existing `legend` object. As long as there is a `'String'` entry for each object in `'PlotChildren'`, it will be rendered in the legend.

For example:

```
y3 = x + 2;
hold on
plot(x, y3, 'gp');

% To make sure we target the right axes, pull the legend's PlotChildren 
% and get the parent axes object
parentaxes = lh.PlotChildren(1).Parent;

% Get new plot object handles from parent axes
newplothandles = flipud(parentaxes.Children); % Flip so order matches

% Generate new legend string
newlegendstr = [lh.String 'Pentagram'];

% Update legend
lh.PlotChildren = newplothandles;
lh.String = newlegendstr;
```

Which returns:

[image: yay]

---

This functionality can be wrapped into a generic helper function to support appending one or more legend entries. We've done so with [`legtools` on GitHub](https://github.com/StackOverflowMATLABchat/legtools)

Answer (score 0):

[As of MATLAB 2017a](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html?rntext=legend&startrelease=R2017a&endrelease=R2017a&category=Graphics&groupby=release&sortby=descending&searchHighlight=legend), legends update automatically when adding or removing graphics objects.

Thus, nothing specific needs to be done now. One creates the legend, then in a loop one can add lines to the axes and they'll automatically appear in the legend.