# Change markers in dynamic plots

Tags: matlab, plot

What I have:

```
hold on
for i =1:length(tspan)
    var{i} = Tv(:,i);
    str{i} = ['t = ',num2str(tspan(i)), ' s'];
    plot(z,var{i},'DisplayName',str{i});
end
legend('-DynamicLegend');
```

This works perfectly (thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685911/dynamic-legend-updates-in-every-recursion)), but it prints out all blue lines.
I tried to set up a `colormap` (the default) and use it like this, but the output was the same

```
plot(z,var{i},'DisplayName',str{i},'Color', colormap(i,:));
```

And I would also like to see different markers for each plot. How is it possible to change them?

**EDIT**

[Thanks to ironzionlion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27543898/change-colors-and-markers-in-dynamic-plots/27545546#27545546) I fixed the colors. **How can I do the same with markers?**

Comment: i generally just make a normal array with with the various symbols and index them

Comment: @chris Good point, but I'd like this to be as automated as possible. Right now I have seven plots, but I might have more or fewer depending on what I need. If I can't do it any other way, I'll set up a 15-symbol array and just pick from it...

Comment: I think this behaviour changed in R2014b (see http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html). If you are using an older release, you have to create your own array of colours. I normally use http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29702-generate-maximally-perceptually-distinct-colors for that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [post that you mention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685911/dynamic-legend-updates-in-every-recursion), you have to define that you will need `i` different colours in your plot. This can be done by using `colors = hsv(i)`

Your plot sentence will then be: `plot(z,var{i},'DisplayName',str{i},'Color', colors(i,:));`

### Update

I am not aware of the existance of `"markermap"`. You could fix the problem just by define upfront the [different markers](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/primitiveline-properties.html) that you want (quick and dirty solution): `mrk={'o','+','*','.'};`

Then you will plot by selecting each time the corresponding marker:

`plot(z,var{i},'DisplayName',str{i},'Color', cmap(i,:),'Marker', mrk{i});`