# Plot with multiple axes but only one legend

Tags: matlab, plot, legend-properties

The following code produces a plot with two lines reffering to the left y-axis and one line referring to the right y-axis. Both plots have their own legend, but I want only one legend listing all 3 lines. I tried to just put the `'y1'`,`'y2'` strings into the 2nd `legend`-command as well, but that didn't work out.

```
line(x,y1,'b','LineWidth',2)

line(x,y2,'Color',[0,0.6,0.5],'LineWidth',2)

legend('y1','y2');

ax1 = gca;
ax2 = axes('Position',ax1.Position,'YAxisLocation','right', 'Color','none','YColor',[255,127,80]/256);
linkaxes([ax1,ax2],'x');

line(x,y3,'Parent',ax2,'LineWidth',2,'Color',[255,127,80]/256)

legend('y3')
```

Comment: Have a look at dynamic legends: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685911/dynamic-legend-updates-in-every-recursion - I haven't flagged as duplicate because I don't know if this will solve your problem, but it sounds like it will.

Comment: @rayryeng it looks like it might actually solve my problem, but i don't get the syntax correct. since I'm not using (and cannot use in this case) the `plot`-command, but `figure` and `line` instead, i don't know where i have to add the `'DisplayName',['y1','y2','y3']` in my case. i tried adding it to the `figure`-command, but matlab says "there is no displayname in figure-class". Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky problem since the legend are somehow connected to the axes. Since you will be creating 2 axes, hence there will be 2 legends. However there is a trick to achieve what you want. Firstly, plot all line on the same axes, then run `legend`. Then create 2nd axes and then move the third line to the 2nd axes. So your code should look like this:

```
% line
line(x,y1,'b','LineWidth',2)
line(x,y2,'Color',[0,0.6,0.5],'LineWidth',2)
l3=line(x,y3,'LineWidth',2,'Color',[255,127,80]/256)

% legend
legend('y1','y2','y3');

% 2nd axes
ax1 = gca;
ax2 = axes('Position',ax1.Position,'YAxisLocation','right', 'Color','none','YColor',[255,127,80]/256);
linkaxes([ax1,ax2],'x');

% move l3 to 2nd axes
set(l3,'Parent',ax2);
```

If you want to use `'DisplayName'`, it meant to be used with `line`

```
line(x,y1,'Color','b','LineWidth',2,'DisplayName','y1');
line(x,y2,'Color',[0,0.6,0.5],'LineWidth',2,'DisplayName','y2');

legend('show');
```