# How to remove entries from an existing figure legend?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a Matlab figure, let's say it's MyFigure.fig.  This figure has 12 curves with its respective legend entries. However, I want to delete one of the curves and its legend. The curve was easy to delete (just selecting it with the cursor and pressing delete), but when I try to delete its legend, I can only delete the name.

I have been looking for this and I have found other ways to do it. I have found helpful the information of the next link

http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/controlling-legends.html

but, I cannot carry it out. The main problem I found here is this:

- If I try to do it like this, I have no problems:

  ```
  Example (not my case):
  x=0:0.01:pi;
  y=sin(x);   H=plot(x,y);
  hAnnotation = get(H, 'Annotation');
  ```
- But, in my case, I don't have to use "plot" because I have already the figure. So, when I open it and I try to get its handle (by *H=gcf* or *H=gca*) and then, I write the code

  ```
  hAnnotation = get(H, 'Annotation');
  ```

I have the next errors:

1. *The name 'Annotation' is not an accessible property for an instance of
   class 'figure'* (in the case of gcf)
2. *The name 'Annotation' is not an accessible property for an instance of
   class 'axes' (in the case of gca)*

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are several points in your code, that are going wrong. Coming straight to your problem, that's what I suggest:

As far as I can see, this is the same issue that is asked and answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418551/adding-to-a-legend-after-each-iteration/19421558#19421558), BUT the other way around:
instead of adding information, you want to remove entries of the legend.
In fact, that is leading to the exact same thing: you want to update the legend.
Thus you can use the same method as described in the mentioned question:

If you plot something, use the 'DisplayName'-parameter. In your example, that would be:

```
plot(x,y, 'DisplayName', 'myNameForThisLineGoesHere');
%now, after you added OR removed a line (etc.), you have to update the legend:
legend('off'); legend('on')
```