# Adding to a legend after each iteration in R

Tags: r, plot, regression, legend

I am plotting several regression lines, distinguished by setting `lty`, into one graph in R by using the `abline` command.

Now, I am now trying to add a legend to the plot to help readers interpret it. It's supposed to be a very basic legend:

> Linetype X = Variable 1
>
> Linetype Y = Variable 2, etc.

Now the [documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/legend.html) on `legend()` makes total sense to me, but I have only succeeded in writing out one legend at a time.

- Is there any way I can iteratively build this legend? I.e. add
  linetype and variable to a blank legend while plotting?
- Or do I have to collect all the info and write it after the plotting
  is done? If so, what would be the most elegant way to do this?

It would be great if I could rely on standard packages for this to make the code more portable.

Apparently there are ways for doing this in [Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19418551/adding-to-a-legend-after-each-iteration), but I could not find anything for R.

Here is my code:

```
cols=c(0:length(v))
count=1
for (v in variables)
    {
    ...
lmodel=lm(v~x);
abline(lmodel, lty=cols[count]);
count=count+1
...
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Would collecting the information you want to have in the legend (e.g. by appending to a list or vector in each repetition of your loop), and after the last `abline` simply plotting the legend *once* solve your problem? This would likely be a much cleaner solution.

Comment: @geekoverdose yes, that sounds like a reasonable thing to do, thanks for the suggestion! i just did not have very good memories of these kind of list/string operations in R, which have always been rather a headache for me...

Comment: no problem, here comes the minimal working example :)

Comment: you sir, are a hero. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This minimal working example of collecting the legend text from all repetitions of your loop should be easy to adapt for your problem:

```
# dummy plot
plot(iris[,1:2])
# empty legend text
legend_text <- c()
for (v in 1:4) {
    abline(v,0, col = v, lty = v)    
    # add next legend text
    legend_text <- c(legend_text, v)  
}
# plot legend once
legend('topright', legend = legend_text, lty=1:4, col=1:4)
```

One more thing: if you run into problems with using a vector, consider using `list()` instead.